# node.js - nested array in mongoose findOneandUpdate with arrayFilter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know this is a duplicate question. But I have hit the same road block a lot of other seem to hit in updating nested arrays. I am able to manually code an index value, but obviously thats not useful in practical api deployment. So can arrayFilters be used on an array with a length of 1? should i restructure the prospect model, and revert this to a subdocument? Any help would be great.

the console Error

MongoError: No array filter found for identifier 'elem' in path 'resoStatus.representation.$[elem].document'

The document in mongo

```
:
Object_id:5f15a5fe911928412c858fb0
name:"State POA"
postedDate:2020-07-19T05:56:19.738+00:00
assigned:5efd0c3d75bb7122943e3a49
```

req.params.id: 5f15a5fe911928412c858fb0

the function that doesnt work

```
router.put(
  "/:id/resoStatus/representation/:id",
  upload,
  auth,
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    const prospect = await Prospect.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "_id": req.body.prospectId },
      {
        "$set": {
          "resoStatus.representation.$[elem].document": req.file.filename,
          "resoStatus.representation.$[elem].updatedDate": req.file.uploadDate,
          "resoStatus.representation.$[elem].id": req.body.id,
        },
        upsert: true,
        arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": ObjectID(req.params.id) }],
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err) res.status(400).json(err);
      }
    );

    console.log(prospect.resoStatus.representation);
    res.status(200).json(prospect);
  }
);
```

the function that does work

```
router.put(
  "/:id/resoStatus/representation/:id",
  upload,
  auth,
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    const prospect = await Prospect.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "_id": req.body.prospectId },
      {
        "$set": {
          "resoStatus.representation.0.document": req.file.filename,
          "resoStatus.representation.0.updatedDate": req.file.uploadDate,
          "resoStatus.representation.0.id": req.body.id,
        },
        upsert: true,
        arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": ObjectID(req.params.id) }],
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err) res.status(400).json(err);
      }
    );

    console.log(prospect.resoStatus.representation);
    res.status(200).json(prospect);
  }
);
```

the mongoose model

```
 representation: [
      {
        document: String,
        name: String,
        postedDate: Date,
        id: String,
        updatedDate: Date,
        endpoint: String,
        assigned: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
      }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `$`-[operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update the first element that matches the query document:

```
"$set": {
          "resoStatus.representation.$.document": req.file.filename,
          "resoStatus.representation.$.updatedDate": req.file.uploadDate,
          "resoStatus.representation.$.id": req.body.id,
        }
```

If you need to update all array elements of the matched document, you can use the [all-positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_%5B%5D):

```
"$set": {
          "resoStatus.representation.$[].document": req.file.filename,
          "resoStatus.representation.$[].updatedDate": req.file.uploadDate,
          "resoStatus.representation.$[].id": req.body.id,
        }
```

Comment: so this will match all or the first with object id?

Comment: i guess elem is something that is hard coded in someone elses schema and gets carried over. I assumed you just needed to sort of map the object as it were. but removing elem with just a blank [] worked! Man is it ever all down hill from here. :D

Comment: No, both queries match the exact same document, i.e. the document that matches the filter `{ "_id": req.body.prospectId }`. Option 1 then updates the first element in the array that satisfies the conditions (filename, date, id). The second one updates all array-elements.

Comment: Happy to help, please accept the answer. Thank you! :)